# check if id exist in other table

Tags: php, mysql

i want to check if `product_id` exist in cart table and if exist define variable `$class = 'show'`

this is code i have:

```
$article = $db->query("
    SELECT 
        b.price as price,
        b.shop_id as shop_id,
        c.image as image,
        c.name as name,
        a.id as id
    FROM products AS a
    INNER JOIN prices AS b ON a.ean = b.sku
    INNER JOIN shops as c on b.shop_id = c.id
    WHERE a.id = '$product_id'
");     
while ($data = $article->fetch_object()) {
    $price = $data->price;
    $price2 = $data->price;
    $price = number_format($price, 2, ',', ''); 
    $shop_id = $data->shop_id;
    $logo = $data->image;
    $name = $data->name;

//some html code here

}
```

now i dont know how to check if that product exist in cart table. in both tables uniqe is `product_id`

Comment: please explain more about your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a `LEFT JOIN` for that purpose (notice the `CASE WHEN .. THEN ..` section). It joins with cart table and selects a column called `exists_in_cart` with a value of 1 if product exists in cart or 0 otherwise):

```
$article = $db->query("
    SELECT 
        b.price as price,
        b.shop_id as shop_id,
        c.image as image,
        c.name as name,
        a.id as id,
        CASE WHEN cart.product_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as exists_in_cart
    FROM products AS a
    INNER JOIN prices AS b ON a.ean = b.sku
    INNER JOIN shops as c on b.shop_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN cart on a.id = cart.product_id
    WHERE a.id = '$product_id'
");
```

You'll then have a 1 if a product exists in a cart or 0 otherwise:

```
$productInCart = $data->exists_in_cart == 1 ? TRUE : FALSE;
if ($productInCart) {
   $class = 'show';
}
else {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check any rows were returned, and if there are, set your variable.

```
if($article->num_rows) {
   $class = "show";
}
```

Or, check that a property is not null.

```
if( is_null($data->name) == FALSE ) {
   $class = "show";
}
```

Comment: fyi: [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) is a property not a function

Comment: in my code missing where i need to check in table named cart is that product exist, code above is just first part, second is missing and that one i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    b.price as price,
    b.shop_id as shop_id,
    c.image as image,
    c.name as name,
    a.id as id,
    CASE WHEN cart.product_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as exists_in_cart
FROM products AS a
INNER JOIN prices AS b ON a.ean = b.sku
INNER JOIN shops as c on b.shop_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN cart on a.id = cart.product_id
WHERE a.id = '$product_id'
```

if product doesn't exists in table this query will return num_rows = 0, you have already choosed only existing products.